# Unix: Where does "ls -l" get comma-separated values in size field for devices?

Tags: c, unix, ls

When I run `ls -l /dev` on OS X I get an output with the following format (but many more files):

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root       wheel            4, 126 Jun 11 20:28 ttywe
crw-rw-rw-  1 root       wheel            4, 127 Jun 11 20:28 ttywf
```

As far as I can tell, it is specific to that folder and I can't find anywhere what that `4,` means.
I am rewriting `ls` in C, so I would like to know what it is, and, if possible, how to retrieve that value in C.

Comment: Device nodes don't have a size. The value you're interpreting as "size" is the minor number.

Comment: BTW -- not specific to that directory at all; device nodes can exist elsewhere as well; having them in `/dev` is simply convention. (Sometimes that convention is enforced for security reasons, but that's done by filesystem mount flags that are off by default -- because it's often useful to have device nodes elsewhere, such as for a chroot).

Comment: BTW, the `c` at the front of the permissions is also important (indicating that this is a character device).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the POSIX specification for `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ls.html):

> If the file is a character special or block special file, the size of the file may be replaced with implementation-defined information associated with the device in question.

In this particular case, you almost certainly have an implementation printing the major and minor device numbers -- the values which would be passed to `mknod` to create a file pointing to the same device. However, no implementation is *required* to provide this information, and your implementation of `ls` can conform with the standard without it.

---

If you want to know how to implement this in C, a good place to start is `man 2 stat`. `st_rdev` is the field you care about in the `struct stat` which this call fills out. On Linux, you can extract the major and minor numbers by calling the macros `MAJOR(stat_result.st_rdev)` and `MINOR(stat_result.st_rdev)` (assuming you told `stat` to write to a structure named `stat_result`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using struct stat for the permission bits and stuff, so it should be easy to code that :)

Comment: And, as a portability note, the major and minor macros (or functions) are in upper-case or lower-case, and found in different headers (`<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/mkdev.h>`, `<sys/sysmacros.h>`, …) on different platforms at different times.  It's a complete PITA to program using them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot :) What worked for me on OS X Yosemite was major() and minor() on <sys/types.h>